# htaccess symfony2 redirect to web directory

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, redirect

I've just published my symfony proyect, but the url is `http://url.com/web/`. I want to change my `.htaccess` to point to `web directory`. So, the url I want it to be like `http://url.com/`. I've tried to change my `.htaccess` but I have not been successful.

Answer (score 6):

my project is in a shared host and i can't create a virtual host. I used this .htaccess file in symfony root and works.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
    RewriteRule ^/web/app_dev.php - [L]
    RewriteRule ^/web/app.php - [L]

    # Fix the bundles folder
    RewriteRule ^bundles/(.*)$ /web/bundles/$1  [QSA,L]

    # Fix the assets folder
    RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1  [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # Change below before deploying to production
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/app.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

https://undebugable.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/symfony2-htaccess-to-redirect-request-from-web-to/

Comment: there is a problem with the favicon icons in the web folder:  "No route found for "GET /favicon-32x32.png" .

Comment: You have to ensure your icon is on /web/assets/favicon-32x32.png. I put my assets on web/assets, not web/

Answer (score 0):

Please read that page and look the Apache configurations.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html